# Mikro-orm Bug: Entity 'undefined' entity was not discovered

Tags: mikro-orm

How can i fix this bug

> Entity 'undefined' entity was not discovered, please make sure to provide it in 'entities' array when initializing the ORM

Comment: This is usually connected to circular dependencies in your entities and the folder based discovery. Try using the `entities: [A, B, C, ...]` instead of `entitiesDirs`. https://mikro-orm.io/docs/installation#possible-issues-with-circular-dependencies

Comment: Thank Martin but this did not correct the problem

Comment: Well with report like this, nobody can help as nobody sees the actual code. If you put together reproduction repository, will be happy to take a look. The error itself means that you have some relationship misconfigured, either because of circular dependency, or you actually have some wrong value there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in a nestjs project with `mikro-orm`.
Using `entities` array instead of `entitiesDirs` in the configuration (as mentioned by Martin), and stopping the dev server and deleting the `/temp` and `/dist` folders before restarting fixed the issue for me.